# CSS Container not growing with grid?

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have a container background defined in CSS like this;

```
.container {
    background:#fff;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: relative;
    width:970px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

The problem is I have a jqGrid put in the bottom of the container (near the bottom edge) and when its initially drawn it does fit inside the container panel and looks correct. Something like this (please pardon my non-l33t graphic skillz):

[alt text http://img67.yfrog.com/img67/7162/screenshot002f.jpg](http://img67.yfrog.com/img67/7162/screenshot002f.jpg)

But then when I populate the grid with rows it outgrows the container and it looks really tacky, something like this (I circled the original container background edges):

[alt text http://img80.yfrog.com/img80/5419/screenshot003fr.jpg](http://img80.yfrog.com/img80/5419/screenshot003fr.jpg)

I am sure its something I am doing wrong with the CSS. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: The problem isn't the width its the height of the container being overlapped by the new height of the now populated grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen many times when you have floats inside. Add a clearing div just before closing container. You should always clean up after floats.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="nav" style="float:left;">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="grid" style="float:left;">
  ...
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!-- this does the trick -->
</div>
```

I disagree with [adding float to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581202/css-container-not-growing-with-grid/1581420#1581420). Although this will work, having unnecessary floats will give you more problems down the road. Only use floats where necessary and clear it when done floating.

Also in my experience, `overflow` doesn't mean anything here unless you define `height`. I don't think setting overflow on container fixes the issue here. Correct me in the comments if I'm wrong.

Comment: Adding overflow:hidden automatically contains floats. (It's much easier than clearfix, too.) If you have a height declared, it will cut it off--if not, just contain them. Of course, then nothing else can escape the container either. +1 for advising against floating everything, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container { overflow:hidden; }
```

assuming you are dealing with floats, this is one way to make the container actually contain them.

Answer (score 0):

Your container is fixed width and won't grow. What you're probably looking for is min-width. In other words, change:

```
width:970px;
```

to:

```
min-width:970px;
```

As a note, IE 6 and 7 treat width as min-width, but other browsers do not.

Comment: I think you meant it the other way around. IE6 doesn't understand min-width. It treats it just like width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this in your CSS:

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp has other options and info related to this.

Comment: Its weird to me how this does expand the container but shows scrollbars both vert and horz. Seems there should be a way to just make the background container resize and not put up scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your float situation for the container and the inside grid, you can do a number of different things. You might be able to get away with just adding a clear,

```
clear:both;
```

You also can float the parent. This is called, setting a float to fix a float. So if your grid has a

```
float:left;
```

Then you can just add

```
float:left;
```

to your container css. I really like the [Complex Spiral article on containing floats](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/).